# Weighted Average of Percentage Increases

Tags: statistics, average

I believe I have quite a simple problem, but want clarification on whether it is the best method to use.

Say I have have insurance line, and the net income (£) from this business for 2011, 2012, 2013 is

1,000,000

4,500,000

5,000,000

respectively.

Hence, the pecentage increase from 11-12 is 350%, and from 12-13 is 11.1%.

Now, the average of these is 180.5%, which is a representation of the average percentage increase across all years, but it has been suggested to me to instead represent the data by a "weighted" average.

I am curious... would the weights be the difference in income from each year?

i.e. Weighted Avg. = $((3.5)*350\% + (0.5)*11.1\%)/4 = 307\%$

or would the weights possibly the values themselves? Or maybe there is another option?

Thanks very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would usually compute the per annum increase:
$$y_t=r^t y_0 \Leftrightarrow r=\left(\frac{y_t}{y_0}\right)^{1/t},$$
where $r-1$ is the increase per annum, $t$ is the amount of time periods (years) and $y_0$ and $y_t$ is in your case the insurance line in the first year and the last year. In your example, $r=\sqrt{5}\approx 2.23$, and the increase per annum is about $120\%$

The advantage of computing like this is that when you actually use $r$, then $y_0*r^t$, by construction, actually gives you the right end value $y_t$. Using your estimate of the annual increase, on the other hand, you get $y_0*(1+1.8)^2\approx 7,840,000$, which is far from $y_2=5,000,000$. Taking any linear average (weighted or unweighted) of a variable that is applied exponentially doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks Nameless.. But what if there is not a per annum increase every year? What if there is a decrease from year 1 to year 2, then this will no longer apply, and maybe my estimate is then a better option. It has been suggested to me (by people above me) that 'a' weighted average would be better - could there be weights that are better to use? Thanks

Comment: No idea about those weights. But you could still use the above exponential method if there are years where $y$ decreases. If there is a decrease in every year, then you would get $0<r<1$, or a negative increase (=decrease).

Comment: I guess the question that is being posed to me, is what is going to happen 'on average', to project what is going to happen next. For example: Say the net worth of a secuirty is as follows: 2009: 5, 2010: 500, 2011: -900, 2012: 5. Using your method, I get an average change of 0%. But we can be quite sure that for 2013 the net worth is going to be different to 5. Hence I require 'some' weighted average?? Thanks again.